# Where / how do you set kCGLOGLPVersion_Legacy?

Tags: opengl, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, legacy-code

I need to use legacy mode for an application that I am porting from Snow Leopard to Lion, to keep the legacy opengl code functioning properly I read that I need to set kCGLOGLPVersion_Legacy for my application profile, or something like that in Appledocumentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_pixelformats/opengl_pixelformats.html

I don't know how or where to set this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it using CGLChoosePixelFormat.

[This description of OpenGL Profiles](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html) says:

> Discussion
>   An OpenGL Profile is requested as part of the pixel format attributes string. When a context is created for a profile, the context must at least implement the requested version of the OpenGL specification. The context may implement a different version of the OpenGL specification as long as the version it implements is compatible with the requested version.

You can find a description of CGLChoosePixelFormat [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGLChoosePixelFormat)

Note that you will have to cast kCGLOGLPVersion_Legacy to (CGLPixelFormatAttribute).